# How to control Google Home volume from Actions on Google

Tags: actions-on-google

Is there any way to allow for volume Home commands (raise/lower by percentage or not) to work while in a third party app? Right now API.ai just fails to handle the command and the AoG api doesnt seem have any commands to affect device volume if we were to handle the commands ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported for actions.

Comment: is this still true for the longform audio / mediaobject responses in v2? Seems weird that you'd be able to play audio, but not control the volume.

Comment: Lots of people ask my Action for the volume to be adjusted (up or down), when I'm playing an mp3 using a normal MediaResponse. It'd be great to be able to do something with that request, other than give the unhelpful "Sorry, I can't do that" response...